# Can't create user from UserAdmin (using SonataUserBundle) . Edit working fine

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony6, sonata-user-bundle

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.partitech.com/blog-technique/symfony/symfony-6-sonata-initialiser-un-projet-symfony-6-sonata-fosuser-media/) to add the SonataUserBundle to my Symfony + Sonata Admin project.

I could create users from the cmd line without a problem, as the article suggests.
But from the UserAdmin it's not working and instead gives 3 errors of empty fields (see screenshot).
But these fields shouldn't be empty:

- createdAt should be filled by prePersist,
- updatedAt should be allowed to be null, since it's part of the Registration group
- and password should be filled by the SonataUserAdmin prePersist, by
  hashing plainPassword.

Somehow, the entity prePersist is not called when creating a new User entity. And also the UserAdmin's prePersist is not called.
[image]

However, editing users is working fine.

Any idea what's going on?
Thank you!